# How would you count different substrings in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML snippet:

```
   <wrapper>
      <item timestamp="19.10.2011 12:05">
         <comment>Used for orderID '011187' with item 'xyz1'</comment>
      </item>
      <item timestamp="01.06.2012 16:25">
         <comment>Used for orderID '011379' with item 'xyz2'</comment>
      </item>
      <item timestamp="06.06.2012 14:32">
         <comment>Used for orderID '011382' with item 'xyz2'</comment>
      </item>
   </wrapper>
```

I want to know how many of each item occurs.
In this case:
- 1 x xyz1
- 2 x xyz2

So somehow you have to loop over all `<item>`, extract the string which is between the quotes (') after the text `with item...`and then count how many times that string occurs in total inside the wrapper element.

How would you solve this in XSLT?

Comment: 1.0 or 2.0? Big difference in string handling between the two.

Comment: "*extract the string which is between the quotes (')*" Which one? There are two in all the instances in the given example. You need to provide a more specific rule.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: I meant the second quotes after "with item...", i added the info in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For XSLT 2 you would do best to go with fafl's answer. If you're stuck with XSLT 1, the following would work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="comment">
        <xsl:variable name="item" select='substring-before(substring-after(., "item &apos;"), "&apos;")' />
        <xsl:variable name="quotedItem" select='concat("item &apos;", $item, "&apos;")' />
        <xsl:if test='generate-id(.) = generate-id(//comment[contains(text(), $quotedItem)])'>
            <xsl:value-of select='count(//comment[contains(text(), $quotedItem)])' />
            <xsl:text> x </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$item" />
            <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Let's break it down a bit. The first template quite simply applies templates recursively. The second template matches all `<comment>` elements.

First the item name is extracted by taking the substring after `item '` and then taking the substring before `'` in that result. This assumes that the item name always occurs in the form `item 'name'`. If not, you'll need to adjust this. The result is assigned to variable `item`. Note that the use of single quotes makes this a bit tricky, as double and single quotes are XML markup. So the `select` attribute value is put between single quotes instead of the standard double quotes, and the single quotes actually intended as text are referenced via `&apos;`.

Then a variable named `quotedItem` is assigned which is basically the string `item 'name'` (with name the actual item value), to make things a bit easier later on. It avoids matching the item name outside of quotes, or partial matches (for example if one comment contained `item 'xy'` and another `item 'xyz'`). Again, this makes assumptions of the input.

Then the test in the `if` element checks if the generated id of the current `<comment>` is the same as the generated id of the last `<comment>` that contains the `quotedItem` substring, so that only for the last occurrence of each item an action is taken. The action, in this case, is to count all the `<comment>` elements which contain the `quotedItem` substring, and output that as `count x item` followed by a carriage return and newline.

The core parts are the variables and the `generated-id` trick. The rest will depend on what you mean to do with the results.

xsltransform link: http://xsltransform.net/a9Giwm

Answer (score 2):

In XSLT 2.0 this works:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="wrapper">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="item/comment"
           group-by="replace(tokenize(., ' ')[last()], '[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '')">
        <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('- ', count(current-group()), ' x ', current-grouping-key(), '&#xa;')"/>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Fiddle: http://xsltransform.net/pNmBxZD

Answer (score 2):

Here's another XSLT 1.0 option using Muenchian grouping (`xsl:key`)...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements= "*"/>

  <xsl:key name="items" match="comment" 
    use="substring-after(normalize-space(),'with item ')"/>

  <xsl:template match="/wrapper">
    <xsl:for-each select="item/comment[count(.|key('items',
      substring-after(normalize-space(),'with item '))[1])=1]">
      <xsl:variable name="items" select="key('items',
        substring-after(normalize-space(),'with item '))"/>
      <xsl:value-of select='concat("- ",count($items)," x ",
        translate(substring-after(normalize-space(),"with item "),"&apos;",""),
        "&#xA;")'/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Example (since everyone else is doing it ;-): http://xsltransform.net/93dEHFs